# nodejs orient-js doesnt execute 'then' function

Tags: node.js, bluebird, orientjs

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');
var util = require('util');
var httpApp = express();
http.createServer(httpApp).listen(8080, function() {
console.log("Server started on port 8080");

//conect to orientdb server
var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2480,
    username: 'root',
    password: '123456'
});

console.log('connected to orientdb.');

//list all databases
server.list()
    .then(function(dbs) {
        console.log('There are ' + dbs.length +' databases on the server.');
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
})
```

and the console result is:

```
Server started on port 8080
connected to orientdb.
```

but nothing happen when I try to display the number of databases. Why `then` or `catch` are not executed? Should I configure something?!?
I want to mention that the `nodejs` server doesn't crash.

Comment: Problem solved. The port should be 2424 because in this case I use binary distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `HTTPport` parameter (in this case `2480`):

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

//server connection
var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    HTTPport: 2480,
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'adminPW'
});

//calculate the number of databases on the server
server.list()
    .then(function (dbs) {
    console.log('There are ' + dbs.length + ' databases on the server.');
});
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
There are 15 databases on the server.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It seems that for not HTTP request the port is 2424.